# Is there a way to get the current time zone in the format the Google Calendar API wants in Python?

Tags: python, timezone, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a python app to interact with Google Calendar and I need help getting the time zone in the format it wants. I tried `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0))).astimezone().tzinfo`,
but that just returned `PST` and I need it to be `America/Los_Angeles`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytz` to localize `datetime` objects in `python`.

```py
import datetime
import pytz

today = datetime.datetime.now()
localized = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the timezone by changing the value of os.environ["TZ"]:

Sample Code:

```
import os
import time

os.environ["TZ"] = "America/New_York"
time.tzset()
```

From there, you can change the format of date by using *`time.strftime(format)`*

**References:**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SettingTheTimezone/